# I want to get yesterday's date time in camel route header

Tags: xml, date, apache-camel

```
<setHeader headerName="order_creation_date">
    <simple resultType="java.lang.String">
        ${date-with-timezone:now:GMT-5:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss}
    </simple>
</setHeader>
```

the above code sets the current date with new york time zone in exchange header. I need 24 hours back date-time from current date in exchange header from camel XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `now-24h` as documented on the simple language
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-base/src/main/docs/simple-language.adoc
Mind that this requires a recent Camel version, so if it does not work tell us what Camel version you use.

Comment: Hi Claus, I would like to ask about Camel documentation. Which is the appropriate place to see the documentation, github or camel.apache.org? Which one is the most updated?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Claus, 
Yes, this is working for me.
I am using camel version 2.19.0.
Thanks.